# Power Automate: Flatten a json object and extract all objects from dynamic amounts of arrays in dynamic paths

Tags: arrays, json, object, extract, power-automate

I've got a bit of a problem. I'm working on a function to handle email and email attachments. I'm getting a response from the Outlook API-function calling the graph-engine with all the attachments an email has and the following is kind of how the response can look:

```
{
   "data1": "hello",
   "data2": "hello",
   "data3": "hello",
   "attachments": [
      {
         "data1": "hello",
         "data2": "hello",
         "data3": "hello"
      },
      {
         "data1": "hello",
         "data2": "hello",
         "data3": "hello",
         "attachments": [
            {
               "data1": "hello",
               "data2": "hello",
               "data3": "hello",
               "attachments": [
                  {
                     "data1": "hello",
                     "data2": "hello",
                     "data3": "hello"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "data1": "hello",
               "data2": "hello",
               "data3": "hello"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Is there any smart way of "flattening" and cleaning out all the irrelevant data and get all the attachments from all the attachment arrays? The amount of arrays and the nesting is entirely dynamic so I need a way to find all attachments-arrays in all levels without caring about how many or few there are.

I have so far experimented with xpath, but it doesn't return all the data from the nodes, it only returns a base64 and a contentType property.

Edit:
This is an example of a "real" response:

```
    {
    "@odata.type": "",
    "id": "",
    "createdDateTime": "2023-08-17T09:49:48Z",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2023-08-17T09:51:24Z",
    "receivedDateTime": "2023-08-17T09:29:08Z",
    "sentDateTime": "2023-08-17T09:29:06Z",
    "hasAttachments": true,
    "internetMessageId": "",
    "subject": "",
    "bodyPreview": "",
    "importance": "normal",
    "conversationId": "=",
    "conversationIndex": "==",
    "isDeliveryReceiptRequested": false,
    "isReadReceiptRequested": false,
    "isRead": true,
    "isDraft": false,
    "webLink": "",
    "internetMessageHeaders": [{
        "name": "Received",
        "value": ""
    }, {
        "name": "Received",
        "value": ""
    }, {
        "name": "Received",
        "value": ""
    }, {
        "name": "Authentication-Results",
        "value": ""
    }, {
        "name": "Content-Type",
        "value": "application/ms-tnef"
    }, {
        "name": "Content-Transfer-Encoding",
        "value": "binary"
    }, {
        "name": "From",
        "value": ""
    }, {
        "name": "To",
        "value": ""
    }, {
        "name": "Subject",
        "value": ""
    }, {
        "name": "Thread-Topic",
        "value": ""
    }, {
        "name": "Thread-Index",
        "value": "=="
    }, {
        "name": "Date",
        "value": "Thu, 17 Aug 2023 09:29:06 +0000"
    }, {
        "name": "Message-ID",
        "value": "<@.eurprd06.prod.outlook.com>"
    }, {
        "name": "Accept-Language",
        "value": "en-US"
    }, {
        "name": "Content-Language",
        "value": "en-US"
    }, {
        "name": "X-MS-Has-Attach",
        "value": "yes"
    }, {
        "name": "X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL",
        "value": "1"
    }, {
        "name": "X-MS-TNEF-Correlator",
        "value": "<@.eurprd06.prod.outlook.com>"
    }, {
        "name": "MIME-Version",
        "value": "1.0"
    }, {
        "name": "X-MS-Exchange-Organization-MessageDirectionality",
        "value": "Originating"
    }, {
        "name": "X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource",
        "value": ".eurprd06.prod.outlook.com"
    }, {
        "name": "X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs",
        "value": "Internal"
    }, {
        "name": "X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthMechanism",
        "value": "04"
    }, {
        "name": "X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Network-Message-Id",
        "value": ""
    }, {
        "name": "X-MS-PublicTrafficType",
        "value": "Email"
    }, {
        "name": "X-MS-TrafficTypeDiagnostic",
        "value": ""
    }, {
        "name": "Return-Path",
        "value": ""
    }, {
        "name": "X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationStartTime",
        "value": "17 Aug 2023 09:29:07.0980 (UTC)"
    }, {
        "name": "X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationStartTimeReason",
        "value": "OriginalSubmit"
    }, {
        "name": "X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationInterval",
        "value": "1:00:00:00.0000000"
    }, {
        "name": "X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationIntervalReason",
        "value": "OriginalSubmit"
    }, {
        "name": "X-MS-Office365-Filtering-Correlation-Id",
        "value": ""
    }, {
        "name": "X-MS-Exchange-AtpMessageProperties",
        "value": "SA|SL"
    }, {
        "name": "X-Microsoft-Antispam",
        "value": "BCL:0;"
    }, {
        "name": "X-Forefront-Antispam-Report",
        "value": ""
    }, {
        "name": "X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-OriginalArrivalTime",
        "value": "17 Aug 2023 09:29:06.7371 (UTC)"
    }, {
        "name": "X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-FromEntityHeader",
        "value": "Hosted"
    }, {
        "name": "X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Id",
        "value": ""
    }, {
        "name": "X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-AuthSource",
        "value": "..prod.outlook.com"
    }, {
        "name": "X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-AuthAs",
        "value": "Internal"
    }, {
        "name": "X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Network-Message-Id",
        "value": ""
    }, {
        "name": "X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-MailboxType",
        "value": "HOSTED"
    }, {
        "name": "X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-UserPrincipalName",
        "value": ""
    }, {
        "name": "X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersStamped",
        "value": ""
    }, {
        "name": "X-MS-Exchange-Transport-EndToEndLatency",
        "value": ""
    }, {
        "name": "X-MS-Exchange-Processed-By-BccFoldering",
        "value": ""
    }, {
        "name": "X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery",
        "value": ""
    }, {
        "name": "X-Microsoft-Antispam-Message-Info",
        "value": ""
    }],
    "sender": {
        "emailAddress": {
            "name": "",
            "address": ""
        }
    },
    "from": {
        "emailAddress": {
            "name": "",
            "address": ""
        }
    },
    "toRecipients": [{
        "emailAddress": {
            "name": "",
            "address": ""
        }
    }],
    "flag": {
        "flagStatus": "notFlagged"
    },
    "attachments": [
        {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.itemAttachment",
        "id": "",
        "lastModifiedDateTime": "2023-08-17T09:51:24Z",
        "name": "",
        "contentType": null,
        "size": 27964,
        "isInline": false,
        "item@odata.associationLink": "",
        "item@odata.navigationLink": "",
        "item": {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.message",
            "id": "",
            "createdDateTime": "2023-08-17T09:49:48Z",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2023-08-17T09:51:24Z",
            "receivedDateTime": "2023-08-17T09:22:03Z",
            "sentDateTime": "2023-08-17T09:22:02Z",
            "hasAttachments": true,
            "internetMessageId": "<",
            "subject": "",
            "bodyPreview": "",
            "importance": "normal",
            "conversationId": "=",
            "conversationIndex": "//==",
            "isDeliveryReceiptRequested": false,
            "isReadReceiptRequested": false,
            "isRead": false,
            "isDraft": false,
            "webLink": "",
            "internetMessageHeaders": [{
                "name": "Received",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "Received",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "Received",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "Authentication-Results",
                "value": "dkim=none (message not signed) header.d=none;dmarc=none action=none header.from=.com;"
            }, {
                "name": "Content-Type",
                "value": "application/ms-tnef"
            }, {
                "name": "Content-Transfer-Encoding",
                "value": "binary"
            }, {
                "name": "From",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "To",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "CC",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "Subject",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "Thread-Topic",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "Thread-Index",
                "value": "//=="
            }, {
                "name": "Date",
                "value": "Thu, 17 Aug 2023 09:22:02 +0000"
            }, {
                "name": "Message-ID",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "Accept-Language",
                "value": "en-US"
            }, {
                "name": "Content-Language",
                "value": "en-US"
            }, {
                "name": "X-MS-Has-Attach",
                "value": "yes"
            }, {
                "name": "X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL",
                "value": "1"
            }, {
                "name": "X-MS-TNEF-Correlator",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "MIME-Version",
                "value": "1.0"
            }, {
                "name": "X-MS-Exchange-Organization-MessageDirectionality",
                "value": "Originating"
            }, {
                "name": "X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs",
                "value": "Internal"
            }, {
                "name": "X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthMechanism",
                "value": "04"
            }, {
                "name": "X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Network-Message-Id",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "X-MS-PublicTrafficType",
                "value": "Email"
            }, {
                "name": "X-MS-TrafficTypeDiagnostic",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "Return-Path",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationStartTime",
                "value": "17 Aug 2023 09:22:02.6308 (UTC)"
            }, {
                "name": "X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationStartTimeReason",
                "value": "OriginalSubmit"
            }, {
                "name": "X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationInterval",
                "value": "1:00:00:00.0000000"
            }, {
                "name": "X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationIntervalReason",
                "value": "OriginalSubmit"
            }, {
                "name": "X-MS-Office365-Filtering-Correlation-Id",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "X-MS-Exchange-AtpMessageProperties",
                "value": "SA|SL"
            }, {
                "name": "X-Microsoft-Antispam",
                "value": "BCL:0;"
            }, {
                "name": "X-Forefront-Antispam-Report",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-OriginalArrivalTime",
                "value": "17 Aug 2023 09:22:02.2082 (UTC)"
            }, {
                "name": "X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-FromEntityHeader",
                "value": "Hosted"
            }, {
                "name": "X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Id",
                "value": "372ee9e0-9ce0-4033-a64a-c07073a91ecd"
            }, {
                "name": "X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-AuthSource",
                "value": "DBAPR06MB7077.eurprd06.prod.outlook.com"
            }, {
                "name": "X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-AuthAs",
                "value": "Internal"
            }, {
                "name": "X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Network-Message-Id",
                "value": "3c705933-1ee4-485d-9d0c-08db9f036a6c"
            }, {
                "name": "X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-MailboxType",
                "value": "HOSTED"
            }, {
                "name": "X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-UserPrincipalName",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersStamped",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "X-MS-Exchange-Transport-EndToEndLatency",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "X-MS-Exchange-Processed-By-BccFoldering",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "X-Microsoft-Antispam-Message-Info",
                "value": ""
            }],
            "body": {
                "contentType": "html",
                "content": ""
            },
            "sender": {
                "emailAddress": {
                    "name": "",
                    "address": ""
                }
            },
            "from": {
                "emailAddress": {
                    "name": "",
                    "address": ""
                }
            },
            "toRecipients": [{
                "emailAddress": {
                    "name": "",
                    "address": ""
                }
            }],
            "ccRecipients": [{
                "emailAddress": {
                    "name": "",
                    "address": ""
                }
            }, {
                "emailAddress": {
                    "name": "",
                    "address": ""
                }
            }],
            "flag": {
                "flagStatus": "notFlagged"
            },
            "attachments": [{
                "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
                "@odata.mediaContentType": "image/png",
                "id": "",
                "lastModifiedDateTime": "2023-08-17T09:51:24Z",
                "name": "image.png",
                "contentType": "image/png",
                "size": 1219,
                "isInline": true,
                "contentId": "",
                "contentLocation": null,
                "contentBytes": ""
            }, {
                "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
                "@odata.mediaContentType": "image/png",
                "id": "",
                "lastModifiedDateTime": "2023-08-17T09:51:24Z",
                "name": "download.png",
                "contentType": "image/png",
                "size": 2222,
                "isInline": false,
                "contentId": null,
                "contentLocation": null,
                "contentBytes": ""
            }]
        }
    }],
    "body": {
        "contentType": "html",
        "content": ""
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but can you provide an example of what you expect the output to be based on what you provided because technically, it's all attachment data.  I understand it's dynamic but when you say "irrelevant data", you haven't told us what this is in relation to the example you provided.  Is there any chance of providing a real example?  Just mask the values if there's anything sensitive or personal.

Comment: I can, but what I'm after is to dynamically find all arrays called "attachments" and extract all the child items from these arrays.

Comment: I can help you with that but you have arrays on arrays. It’s all possible but it’s also recursive. I need an example of an output.

Comment: I added an example of the output. As you can see the attachments arrays contain x items which themselves may have an attachments array with x items in them and so on, so forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be ideal (i.e. you don't have a premium subscription and you're not willing to spend the money) but the only real way to do this is with some coding smarts.

Luckily for you, the **Advanced Data Operations** connector has a `C# Script Execute` operation that will give you what you want.  It may not be preferrable but really, this is the only way unless you want to spin up some external service to do it for you.

https://www.statesolutions.com.au/c-script-execute/

https://www.statesolutions.com.au/pricing/

[image: Script]

I loaded your data into a variable called `Data`.  I then use that in the step above.

These are the parameters that were passed in to the C# script operation ...

**C# Script**

```
JObject data = JObject.FromObject(parameters.Data);

var attachments = data.Descendants().OfType<JProperty>().Where(x => x.Name.ToLower() == "attachments" && x.Value.Type == JTokenType.Array).ToList();

return attachments.Select(x => JObject.Parse("{ " + x.ToString() + " }")).ToList();
```

**Parameters**

```
{
  "Data": @{variables('Data')}
}
```

When it then runs, it gives you an array of attachments back as per the payload you provided.

#### Result

[image: Result]

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
        "Cache-Control": "private",
        "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
        "Vary": "Accept-Encoding",
        "Request-Context": "appId=cid-v1:e3ac02f4-c3f7-40d4-b60c-8de25b6b366d",
        "SS-ADO-Instance-No": "3",
        "SS-ADO-Script-Compilation-Duration": "0.4725908",
        "SS-ADO-Script-Duration": "0.0225445",
        "SS-ADO-Product-Id": "ado-standard-unlimited",
        "SS-ADO-Total-Duration": "0.803677",
        "Timing-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "x-ms-apihub-cached-response": "false",
        "x-ms-apihub-obo": "false",
        "Date": "Fri, 18 Aug 2023 13:07:25 GMT",
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    },
    "body": {
        "returnValue": [
            {
                "attachments": [
                    {
                        "contentType": null,
                        "id": "",
                        "isInline": false,
                        "item": {
                            "attachments": [
                                {
                                    "contentBytes": "",
                                    "contentId": "",
                                    "contentLocation": null,
                                    "contentType": "image/png",
                                    "id": "",
                                    "isInline": true,
                                    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2023-08-17T09:51:24Z",
                                    "name": "image.png",
                                    "odata.mediaContentType": "image/png",
                                    "odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
                                    "size": 1219
                                },
                                {
                                    "contentBytes": "",
                                    "contentId": null,
                                    "contentLocation": null,
                                    "contentType": "image/png",
                                    "id": "",
                                    "isInline": false,
                                    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2023-08-17T09:51:24Z",
                                    "name": "download.png",
                                    "odata.mediaContentType": "image/png",
                                    "odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
                                    "size": 2222
                                }
                            ],
                            "body": {
                                "content": "",
                                "contentType": "html"
                            },
                            "bodyPreview": "",
                            "ccRecipients": [
                                {
                                    "emailAddress": {
                                        "address": "",
                                        "name": ""
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "emailAddress": {
                                        "address": "",
                                        "name": ""
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "conversationId": "=",
                            "conversationIndex": "//==",
                            "createdDateTime": "2023-08-17T09:49:48Z",
                            "flag": {
                                "flagStatus": "notFlagged"
                            },
                            "from": {
                                "emailAddress": {
                                    "address": "",
                                    "name": ""
                                }
                            },
                            "hasAttachments": true,
                            "id": "",
                            "importance": "normal",
                            "internetMessageHeaders": [
                                {
                                    "name": "Received",
                                    "value": ""
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "Received",
                                    "value": ""
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "Received",
                                    "value": ""
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "Authentication-Results",
                                    "value": "dkim=none (message not signed) header.d=none;dmarc=none action=none header.from=.com;"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "Content-Type",
                                    "value": "application/ms-tnef"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "Content-Transfer-Encoding",
                                    "value": "binary"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "From",
                                    "value": ""
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "To",
                                    "value": ""
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "CC",
                                    "value": ""
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "Subject",
                                    "value": ""
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "Thread-Topic",
                                    "value": ""
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "Thread-Index",
                                    "value": "//=="
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "Date",
                                    "value": "Thu, 17 Aug 2023 09:22:02 +0000"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "Message-ID",
                                    "value": ""
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "Accept-Language",
                                    "value": "en-US"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "Content-Language",
                                    "value": "en-US"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "X-MS-Has-Attach",
                                    "value": "yes"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL",
                                    "value": "1"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "X-MS-TNEF-Correlator",
                                    "value": ""
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "MIME-Version",
                                    "value": "1.0"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "X-MS-Exchange-Organization-MessageDirectionality",
                                    "value": "Originating"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource",
                                    "value": ""
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs",
                                    "value": "Internal"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthMechanism",
                                    "value": "04"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Network-Message-Id",
                                    "value": ""
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "X-MS-PublicTrafficType",
                                    "value": "Email"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "X-MS-TrafficTypeDiagnostic",
                                    "value": ""
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "Return-Path",
                                    "value": ""
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationStartTime",
                                    "value": "17 Aug 2023 09:22:02.6308 (UTC)"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationStartTimeReason",
                                    "value": "OriginalSubmit"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationInterval",
                                    "value": "1:00:00:00.0000000"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationIntervalReason",
                                    "value": "OriginalSubmit"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "X-MS-Office365-Filtering-Correlation-Id",
                                    "value": ""
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "X-MS-Exchange-AtpMessageProperties",
                                    "value": "SA|SL"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "X-Microsoft-Antispam",
                                    "value": "BCL:0;"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "X-Forefront-Antispam-Report",
                                    "value": ""
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-OriginalArrivalTime",
                                    "value": "17 Aug 2023 09:22:02.2082 (UTC)"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-FromEntityHeader",
                                    "value": "Hosted"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Id",
                                    "value": "372ee9e0-9ce0-4033-a64a-c07073a91ecd"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-AuthSource",
                                    "value": "DBAPR06MB7077.eurprd06.prod.outlook.com"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-AuthAs",
                                    "value": "Internal"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Network-Message-Id",
                                    "value": "3c705933-1ee4-485d-9d0c-08db9f036a6c"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-MailboxType",
                                    "value": "HOSTED"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-UserPrincipalName",
                                    "value": ""
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersStamped",
                                    "value": ""
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "X-MS-Exchange-Transport-EndToEndLatency",
                                    "value": ""
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "X-MS-Exchange-Processed-By-BccFoldering",
                                    "value": ""
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery",
                                    "value": ""
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "X-Microsoft-Antispam-Message-Info",
                                    "value": ""
                                }
                            ],
                            "internetMessageId": "<",
                            "isDeliveryReceiptRequested": false,
                            "isDraft": false,
                            "isRead": false,
                            "isReadReceiptRequested": false,
                            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2023-08-17T09:51:24Z",
                            "odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.message",
                            "receivedDateTime": "2023-08-17T09:22:03Z",
                            "sender": {
                                "emailAddress": {
                                    "address": "",
                                    "name": ""
                                }
                            },
                            "sentDateTime": "2023-08-17T09:22:02Z",
                            "subject": "",
                            "toRecipients": [
                                {
                                    "emailAddress": {
                                        "address": "",
                                        "name": ""
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "webLink": ""
                        },
                        "item@odata.associationLink": "",
                        "item@odata.navigationLink": "",
                        "lastModifiedDateTime": "2023-08-17T09:51:24Z",
                        "name": "",
                        "odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.itemAttachment",
                        "size": 27964
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "attachments": [
                    {
                        "contentBytes": "",
                        "contentId": "",
                        "contentLocation": null,
                        "contentType": "image/png",
                        "id": "",
                        "isInline": true,
                        "lastModifiedDateTime": "2023-08-17T09:51:24Z",
                        "name": "image.png",
                        "odata.mediaContentType": "image/png",
                        "odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
                        "size": 1219
                    },
                    {
                        "contentBytes": "",
                        "contentId": null,
                        "contentLocation": null,
                        "contentType": "image/png",
                        "id": "",
                        "isInline": false,
                        "lastModifiedDateTime": "2023-08-17T09:51:24Z",
                        "name": "download.png",
                        "odata.mediaContentType": "image/png",
                        "odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
                        "size": 2222
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "log": []
    }
}
```

Further to that, if I round the answer out by throwing your original payload at it, this is the result.

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
        "Cache-Control": "private",
        "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
        "Vary": "Accept-Encoding",
        "Request-Context": "appId=cid-v1:e3ac02f4-c3f7-40d4-b60c-8de25b6b366d",
        "SS-ADO-Instance-No": "3",
        "SS-ADO-Script-Compilation-Duration": "5.5440585",
        "SS-ADO-Script-Duration": "0.0381805",
        "SS-ADO-Product-Id": "ado-standard-unlimited",
        "SS-ADO-Total-Duration": "6.915195",
        "Timing-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "x-ms-apihub-cached-response": "false",
        "x-ms-apihub-obo": "false",
        "Date": "Mon, 21 Aug 2023 05:46:13 GMT",
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    },
    "body": {
        "returnValue": [
            {
                "attachments": [
                    {
                        "data1": "hello",
                        "data2": "hello",
                        "data3": "hello"
                    },
                    {
                        "attachments": [
                            {
                                "attachments": [
                                    {
                                        "data1": "hello",
                                        "data2": "hello",
                                        "data3": "hello"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "data1": "hello",
                                "data2": "hello",
                                "data3": "hello"
                            },
                            {
                                "data1": "hello",
                                "data2": "hello",
                                "data3": "hello"
                            }
                        ],
                        "data1": "hello",
                        "data2": "hello",
                        "data3": "hello"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "attachments": [
                    {
                        "attachments": [
                            {
                                "data1": "hello",
                                "data2": "hello",
                                "data3": "hello"
                            }
                        ],
                        "data1": "hello",
                        "data2": "hello",
                        "data3": "hello"
                    },
                    {
                        "data1": "hello",
                        "data2": "hello",
                        "data3": "hello"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "attachments": [
                    {
                        "data1": "hello",
                        "data2": "hello",
                        "data3": "hello"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "log": []
    }
}
```

Comment: That's so great! I had completely missed that you can run C# snippets!

Would you say it'd be easy to dynamically flatten all the arrays and get it into a single array?

Comment: There’s another operation that flattens an object array but not sure if the outputs suits your requirement. Either way, the C# operation can do A LOT.

Comment: Highly appreciated, I think I can work with this. :)